# QGIS Plugin with Main Window

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am new in QGIS plugin development using Python and Qt designer. Previously, I did lot of AddIns development for ArcMap using C#. I am using Plugin builder to develop the plugin.

Is there any way I can create a basic 'Hello World' plugin using windows form not the dialog with button template provided by the plugin builder?

Comment: The plugin [Auxiliary Window](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/auxiliarywindow_plugin/) works using `QMainWindow` instead of a dialog or dockwidget. You could try installing this and have a look at the source code =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any .ui file(designed the way u want) by converting it to .py and then importing it into the main python file of your plugin(since u don't want the default dialog with buttons)